# How does BitLocker encrypt old data on a used drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, encryption, windows-11, bitlocker

How exactly does Bitlocker encrypt deleted data on a used drive if “encrypt whole drive” option is selected?

Normally encryption copies existing data and writes it to the disk as encrypted data, and the old unencrypted data is marked for deletion and will be overwritten when used at some point in the future. But how does bitlocker lock the drive’s old  deleted data on it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any concrete information to back this up, but I'd assume it just reads the entire drive (with no regard for files), encrypting the stream of data and writing it back. Since we know that when a computer "deletes" a file the space used by that file is simply marked free, this free space is simply encrypted along with all the currently existing files.

The only alternative is that Windows encrypts only the used space, then just writes garbage to the new space. This should be fine for security (and it would be faster since it does not need to read first), but then users wouldn't be able to effectively run file recovery software.